# Audio Volume Limited By OS (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, audio

I am using Windows 7 (64 bit) on a desktop PC and am having trouble making the audio output at the correct volume. 
Despite the volume of both the system and the program being set to maximum, when viewing audio levels in the mixer the system clearly shows that the final output volume is significantly less than what the program is trying to output.

[image: Screenshot to help explain.]

(Screenshot is of the Windows 7 Volume mixer, with the dials of all programs and the dial for the device set to 100%, but the levels for the device being less than the levels of the programs.)

This happens in several programs (both winamp and windows media player, for example,) and after restarting the system.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you out, enabling Loudness Equalization by Windows key + R mmsys.cpl and click OK, double click on your current audio device and then go to Enhancements tab, and then checking on the Loudness Equalization tab and click OK.

Comment: This makes it quieter.